# Use category "Home" and "Default" for create a custom home-screen replacement Android TV (not work same Android Phone )?

Tags: android, android-tv

My purpose is replace home_screen for Android TV.
And I use this tutorial :
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-custom-launcher-on-android--cms-21358

Two lines code in AndroidManifest.xml will replace home_screen in Android Phone:

```
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

But it not work in Android TV, no replace home_screen when click button home and it appear like normal app in home screen.
And i still not find any document about set home_screen android TV.
Can anyone know the solution with my issue?
thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand from a thread in this [discussion about Android TV home screen](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191828), it is not possible at all.

Comment: Thanks ULazdins, i understand more the problem from your link. :)